# How to open URI from Android notification when the app on background in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had that method to open URI from notification but it works only when the app is on foreground. What I can add to code to make the notification open URI even if the app is in the background? This method is called in `class PushNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService`

```
void openAnotherApp(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage, Context context, String title, String body, String commingUrl) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(commingUrl));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Did you try "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />" in AndroidManifest.xml? There are also "Alternatives to using wake locks" --> your search ...

Comment: yes i already add this permission to manifest @sidcoder

Comment: mr @sidcoder i found an answer am going to answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your MyFirebaseMessagingService class that extends FirebaseMessagingService class use this method

```
 private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody,String key,String value) {
    //'MainActivity' is the target activity. When notification will be clicked, 'MainActivity' will be triggered
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    if (value!= null) {
        intent.putExtra(key, value);
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                    .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                messageTitle,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

and call it in the same class in onMessageReceived method and as  arguments give it

```
    String title = "";
    String message = "";
    String dataKey = remoteMessage.getData().get("openApp");
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        try {
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
sendNotification(title, message,"openApp",dataKey);
```

and finnelly use this code on your main activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("openApp")) {
        String url = bundle.getString("openApp");
        System.out.println(url);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));


    }
```

And now if you send from Firebase a link like data with the key "open App" the notification that appear when you click it it will open main activity then it will open the link.

Comment: i think it's better to use in app messaging rather then notification to open uri